# How do I prevent AngularJS2 to throw an error when the server responds with 410 (gone)

Tags: angular

I have an AngularJS2 application that does a delete on a resource. The server deletes the resource and answers with 410-GONE. AngularJS2 sees that as an error. How can I tell AngularJS2 that 410 is a correct answer?

My code:

```
deleteOrganisatie(id: number) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.delete(this._url + id, options)
        .map(res => <Melding>res.json().melding)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
private handleError(error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

Needless to say that the resource is deleted on the server.

Comment: Why is 410 Not an error?

Comment: 410 means that resource was deleted before your request, so its error.

Comment: Sounds similar to https://github.com/angular/http/issues/52

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by returning the response with `Observable.of` in your `handleError` method:

```
deleteOrganisatie(id: number) {
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  return this.http.delete(this._url + id, options)
    .map(res => <Melding>res.json().melding)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response) {
  if (error.status === 410) {
    return Observable.of(error.json());
  } else {
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```